# View Tag Descriptions in Android App

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I will occasionally take a look at the [Tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) section on the site and select one I'm not familiar with just to read some posts on different languages, plugins, etc. that I don't work with on a daily basis. I always read the description below the tag but I don't see where I can view it within the app.

When I click on the site name and switch from `Questions` to `Tags`, I was trying to think of a way to include a way to view a brief description of the tags, similar to the link above.

My thought was if you long clicked on a tag, it would pop up a brief description of that tag. When you just clicked on it, it would search questions with that tag, as it currently does.

I can see where there can be arguments made for and against this idea but just wanted to throw it out there. I'm curious to know what others think though. Good idea, dumb idea, possibly a better way, not worth it, etc.?

I'm on version 0.1.70

Comment: I think it's a great idea, it would have to have a more trimmed description than on the website which might lower the usefulness though.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi yes, that was a one of my worries. I looked for some of the longer ones and tried to visualize how much space it might take up. Trying to picture it in my head, it seemed like there would be enough space, but then again imagination definitely isn't reality!